# How to increase the execution time in perl?

Tags: perl, apache2, cgi, execution-time

I am trying to run a Perl CGI script (named script.cgi) on apache2 server but after executing two or three commands, it stops with errors in the log file:

"AH01215: Fatal Error:: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/script.cgi"

"AH01215: Program halted !!: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/script.cgi"

It successfully executes the first three external commands mentioned in the script but fails at the fourth one as it takes more time in generating complete results. I also tried printing the output of the command so that I could know whether the command is being executed or not, and I found that it is being executed but getting failed after a specific period of time.

I tried using Time::Out module but it is not working either. The external commands are being executed in backticks(``) because the system() is not capturing output and exec() does not wait for the command to finish and starts executing the next command.

Is there any way I could modify the timeout settings in apache2? Because I tried that too but I couldn't find any file or mod for this purpose. Please help me out.

Comment: What are the _exact_ error messages you're seeing? "Failed!!!" and "Program halted!!!" are not standard error messages for any of the software you've mentioned in your question.

Comment: AH01215: Fatal Error:: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/script.cgi
AH01215: Program halted !!: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/script.cgi

I have edited the question also.

Comment: HTTP isn't designed for what you're doing. You want something that starts those commands in the background and allow subsequent visits to track the progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In httpd.conf there is a [Timeout](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout) directive. It usually defaults to 60 seconds.

Comment: But there is no httpd.conf file exists in apache2.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your answers. I figured out that the problem was the version of the binary. The version which was installed via apt-get was different than that of the source code. I removed the source code binary and it worked!

Comment: @user8392790 It might be named apache2.conf.